# twitter is not redirecting to the callback url in android app

Tags: android, twitter, callback, twitter4j

My aim is to allow Twitter logins using twitter4j.   [I used this as reference.](https://github.com/Sheikh-Aman/Android_Samples/blob/master/1.%20Sign-inWithTwitterT4J/src/com/aman/samples/t4jsignin/Main.java)

The problem is that at line 64, it calls `getAuthenticationURl()`. When I execute it takes me to the login page, instead of the page where I can allow/disallow my app access to the ppl's account.
However, if I change it to `getAuthorizationUrl()` it takes to the correct page.

1) So what is the difference between the two?

2) This is the important question. I am providing the code below.

```
package com.example.twitter;



import twitter4j.Twitter;
import twitter4j.TwitterException;
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory;
import twitter4j.http.AccessToken;
import twitter4j.http.RequestToken;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class WriteTweet extends Activity{
    public final static String consumerKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    public final static String consumerSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    private final String CALLBACKURL = "T4J_OAuth://callback";
    Twitter twitter;
    RequestToken requestToken;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        loginUser();
    }

    private void loginUser() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
            twitter.setOAuthConsumer(consumerKey, consumerSecret);
            requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken(CALLBACKURL);
            String authUrl = requestToken.getAuthorizationURL();
            this.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                    .parse(authUrl)));
        } catch (TwitterException ex) {
            Toast.makeText(this, ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.e("in Main.OAuthLogin", ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.e("hi","hi");
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        Uri uri = intent.getData();
        try {
            String verifier = uri.getQueryParameter("oauth_verifier");
            AccessToken accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(requestToken,
                    verifier);
            String token = accessToken.getToken(), secret = accessToken
                    .getTokenSecret();
            displayTimeLine(token, secret); //after everything, display the first tweet 

        } catch (TwitterException ex) {
            Log.e("Main.onNewIntent", "" + ex.getMessage());
        }

    }
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    void displayTimeLine(String token, String secret) {
        Log.e("display","timeline");
    }

}
```

the manifest is

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.twitter"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application

        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <activity android:name=".ListTweets" >

        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".WriteTweet"> 
                <intent-filter>  
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />  
                    <data android:scheme="T4J_OAuth" android:host="callback" />
                </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ViewFollowers">

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The problem is that it redirects me to https://mobile.twitter.com/ 
and I cant figure out what am doing wrong. The problem exist no matter if whether `getAuthenticationUrl()` or `getAuthorizationUrl()` is used. I had provided a dummy url in the `callback_url` field in Twitter. 
If I didn't provide a `callbackurl` in code and in the twitter page it will give me a pin number. But that is not what I want. I need my twitter to redirect to my app. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the way I got around the problem,

1. create a web-view and load the conformation page of twitter from within your app.

   ```
   vw = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.loginView);
   vw.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
       @Override
           public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
           return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
       }
   }); vw.loadUrl(authUrl);
   ```
2. Once you receive a callback_url, get the ' oauth_verifier '

   ```
               Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
               String verifier = uri.getQueryParameter("oauth_verifier");
   ```
3. Use this verifier to get access and do what you want. In my case I destroy the webview and load the activity I require.

Answer (score 2):

Use below URL as a Callback URL.

```
public static final String  CALLBACK_URL = "x-oauthflow-twitter://callback";
```

and see below link for more information about twitter integration in android application.

[Twitter Integration](http://androidcodeexamples.blogspot.in/2011/12/how-to-integrate-twitter-in-android.html)

Comment: No, it doesn't work as expected. Now am in a callback-loop. It redirects to different authorization pages all the time.

Comment: @emiljho See above link for more information, it is working in my application.

Comment: Here is the code according to your blog https://gist.github.com/3528561. It isnt working. I dont think the problem is with the callback_url.

Comment: @emiljho Are you testing this application on which API version?