# twitter is not redirecting to android app

Tags: android, twitter

I am developing app to integrate twitter with android app. I was able to open browser and authenticate, after authentication twitter url not returning to android app.

I searched and found call back should be scheme://host but twitter is not accepting this as valid url.

Please help to find correct way to get callback from twitter to android app.

Comment: try this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12196611/twitter-is-not-redirecting-to-the-callback-url-in-android-app

Comment: Lydia, which twitter jar are you using in your app?

Comment: @pratik twitter4j-core-4.0.1.jar

Comment: @Lydia twitter has updated its api, so you need to use twitter4j-core-3.0.4 jar, if you need then let me know.

Comment: you need to pass valid call back url. use http://www.google.com or other valid url and set it is in Twitter developer page and use same inside ur app as well.

Comment: @pratik yes give me the link to download, In net I found one link but that is not downloading the jar.

Comment: @chet's yes I gave valid call back url also, that helped to authenticate twitter but I was not redirected to android app

Comment: @Lydia actually I dont have url, I have jar itself, may I send you in your mail? If you dont mind

Comment: @Lydia ok lydia, delete your mail from here

Comment: @Lydia hey is that useful or not?

Comment: @partik I was trying, still now I was unable to redirect to android app

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55197/discussion-between-pratik-and-lydia).

Comment: Use this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34449673/twitter-login-by-using-webview) (its very clear)