# Twitter login by using WebView

Tags: android, twitter, webview

Hi I completed the twitter login by using browser

**Code**

**TwitLoginActivity.java (Main activity)**

```
package com.app.twitlogin;

import twitter4j.Twitter;
import twitter4j.TwitterException;
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory;
import twitter4j.User;
import twitter4j.auth.AccessToken;
import twitter4j.auth.RequestToken;
import twitter4j.conf.Configuration;
import twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class TwitLoginActivity extends Activity {

static String TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY;
static String TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET;
static String TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL;
static String URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_VERIFIER;

private static Twitter twitter;

Button btnActualLoginTwitter;

private static RequestToken requestToken;

String twitUserID, twitUserName, twitAccessToken, twitTokenSecret, twitProfileImg;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_twit_login);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 11) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }

    TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY = getString(R.string.twitter_consumer_key);
    TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET = getString(R.string.twitter_consumer_secret);
    TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL = getString(R.string.twitter_callback);
    URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_VERIFIER = getString(R.string.twitter_oauth_verifier);

    btnActualLoginTwitter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_twit_login);

    btnActualLoginTwitter.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            btnActualLoginTwitter.setClickable(false);

            Runnable buttonClickable = new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    btnActualLoginTwitter.setClickable(true);
                }
            };

            Handler pdCanceller = new Handler();
            pdCanceller.postDelayed(buttonClickable, 2000);

            Log.e("Came", "Came");

            loginToTwitter();

        }
    });

    Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
    if (uri != null && uri.toString().startsWith(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL)) {

        String verifier = uri.getQueryParameter(URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_VERIFIER);

        try {
            AccessToken accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(requestToken, verifier);

            twitUserID = "" + twitter.getId();
            twitUserName = twitter.getScreenName();
            twitAccessToken = accessToken.getToken();
            twitTokenSecret = accessToken.getTokenSecret();

            User user = twitter.showUser(twitter.getId());
            twitProfileImg = user.getProfileImageURL();

            Log.e("twitUserID", twitUserID);
            Log.e("twitUserName", twitUserName);
            Log.e("twitAccessToken", twitAccessToken);
            Log.e("twitTokenSecret", twitTokenSecret);
            Log.e("twitProfileImg", twitProfileImg);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Twitter Login Error", "" + e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}

 private void loginToTwitter() {
    ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
    builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
    Configuration configuration = builder.build();

    TwitterFactory factory = new TwitterFactory(configuration);
    twitter = factory.getInstance();

    Log.e("TwitterLoginObject", twitter + "");

    try {
        requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL);
        this.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(requestToken.getAuthenticationURL())));

    } catch (TwitterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.twit_login, menu);
    return true;
 }

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
  }
```

**Strings.xml**

```
<string name="twitter_consumer_key">May Key</string>
<string name="twitter_consumer_secret">My secret</string>
<string name="twitter_callback">oauth://t4jsample</string>
<string name="twitter_oauth_verifier">oauth_verifier</string>
```

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.app.twitlogin"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".TwitLoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="t4jsample"
                    android:scheme="oauth" />
            </intent-filter>


        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Now I want to login by using web view not browser (Why because some times twitter not redirects to my app). For this requirement i saw the almost all suggestions in google and SO but i fail to achieve this. So, please help me to login by using WebView

Comment: You can use Fabric, the sdk will launch a native login intent if the twitter is app on the device, if the twitter app isnt found on the device it uses a webview.

Comment: Hi Malek Hijazi, i'm implementing now by using Fabric.

Comment: @Malek Hijazi: Fabric only supports the android studio but i'm doing it in eclipse can you help it to do in eclipse

Comment: check this https://docs.fabric.io/android/fabric/eclipse.html

Comment: check this link for full and easy explanation about integrating twitter login to your app - https://docs.fabric.io/android/twitter/authentication.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strp 1:

In loginToTwitter() do like this:

```
if (!isLoggedIn) {
        final ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(consumerKey);
        builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(consumerSecret);

        final Configuration configuration = builder.build();
        final TwitterFactory factory = new TwitterFactory(configuration);
        twitter = factory.getInstance();

        try {
            requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken(callbackUrl);

            final Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), WebViewActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(WebViewActivity.EXTRA_URL, requestToken.getAuthenticationURL());
            startActivityForResult(intent, WEBVIEW_REQUEST_CODE);

        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Step 2:

And create webviewclient by extend WebViewClient in WebViewActivity like [here](http://hastebin.com/haqanesatu.java)

Step 3:

And implement 'onActivityResult' in your main activity like:

```
if (requestCode == WEBVIEW_REQUEST_CODE) {
        try {
            String verifier = data.getExtras().getString(oAuthVerifier);
            AccessToken accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(requestToken, verifier);

            long userID = accessToken.getUserId();
            final User user = twitter.showUser(userID);
            String username = user.getName();

            saveTwitterInfo(accessToken);
            String id = mSharedPreferences.getString(WSKeys.TwitterClass.PREF_USER_ID, "");
            String name = mSharedPreferences.getString(WSKeys.TwitterClass.PREF_USER_NAME, "");
            wscallSocialSignIn("", id, accessToken.toString(), name, image, "Twitter");
        } catch (Exception exception) {

        }
    }
```

Comment: @ for future users: Fallow this example https://www.dropbox.com/s/9l6s10jxnubb4wm/TwitLogin.rar